# Error in progressbar function in jquery. Getting an error as Progressbar does not exist on type Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I m trying to use jquery progress bar inside an angular application.progress bar is for kendo file upload control. For below code getting an error as progress bar does not exist on tyle jquery.
$(#progressbar).progressbar("value",progress)

I have added jquery libraries by including @types/jquery version 2.0.46

Answer (score 0):

[Progressbar](https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) is part of JQuery UI library, so you need to install it first as below:

```
npm install jquery-ui-dist --save
```

And put these files in `angular.json`

```json
"styles": ["./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css"],
"scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js"]
```

Then you can use `progressbar` method as following:

```js
$("#progressbar").progressbar({value: progress})
```

Here is a working example:  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomplete-jqueryui-hcn1u2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

P.S.: it is not best practice to use JQuery with Angular, try to use [Angular Material progress-bar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) instead